# String separator, similar to strtok

Tags: c, strings

I made a string separator below. It's like strtok, but it separates based on entire strings instead of single char delimiters. Any comments/answers on how I could improve the performance or readability would be great. I'm also leaking some memory according to valgrind, but that is only a minor concern for my use case.

It takes two char arrays, a buffer(string?) and a separator. It returns an array of strings containing all of the separated strings. For example, if the buffer is `foobar` and the separator is `foo`, it'll return `{"bar", NULL}`. But if I'm passed `foobarfoobarfoobar` and the separator is `bar`, it'll return `{"foo", "foo", "foo", NULL}`.

Edit: Comments added to clarify intended functionality.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **sepstr(const char *buf, const char *sep){
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, stringCount = 0;

    /* If separator > buffer, return NULL */
    while (buf[i]) i++;
    while (sep[j]) j++;
    if (j > i) return NULL;

    char **strings = malloc(0);

    /* While we're not at the end of the buffer */
    while (*(buf+k)){
        /* If the characters match, check to see if it is the separator */
        if (*(buf+k) == *(sep)){
            for (l = 0; l < j; l++){
                /* If it isn't the separator, break */
                if (*(buf+k+l) != *(sep+l)) break;
                /* If it is the separator and the separator isn't the
                    beginning, add buf to buf+k bytes as a string */
                if (l == j-1 && k != 0){
                    strings = realloc(strings, (stringCount+1)*sizeof (char *));
                    strings[stringCount] = malloc(k+1);
                    memcpy(strings[stringCount++], buf, k);
                    buf += (j + k), k = -1;
                /* If it is the separator, but it's the beginning
                    of the string, skip it */
                } else if (l == j-1 && k == 0) {
                    buf += j, k = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Add a string for the left over bytes if sep isn't the end */
    if (i != k && *(buf)){
        while (buf[l]) l++;
        strings = realloc(strings, (stringCount+1) * sizeof (char *));
        strings[stringCount] = malloc(l+1);
        memcpy(strings[stringCount++], buf, l);
    }

    /* Append NULL to array of strings */
    strings = realloc(strings, (stringCount+1) * sizeof (char *));
    strings[stringCount] = malloc(sizeof NULL);
    strings[stringCount] = NULL;

    return strings;
}

int main(){
    const char buffer[] = "foobarfoobarfoobar";
    const char separator[] = "bar";
    char **strings = sepstr(buffer, separator);

    while(*strings){
        printf("%s\n", *(strings));
        free(*(strings++));
    }

    free(strings);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible suggestion: Replace memcpy with `for (l = 0; l < k; l++) strings[stringCount][l] = *(buf+l);`to remove dependency on `string.h` and remove `string.h`.

Comment: We expect your code to be working correctly as intended. Please fix any [known memory leaks](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2337/9357) before proceeding with a review.

Comment: @200_success Arguably, the code still works as intended. The issue here isn't really the memory leaks as it has no ill-effects on the actual outcome of the program. [A short-lived program might suffer no apparent ill effects from a memory leak. In that case, the question could be considered on-topic, and the sloppiness would be fair material to be addressed in an answer.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/are-code-snippets-with-known-memory-leaks-broken)

Comment: +1 for using Valgrind; -1 for ignoring its findings.

Comment: @TobySpeight Didn't ignore its findings. Check the edits on the original post. I had originally wanted help with fixing the memory leaks, but because of that 200_success marked it as off-topic. In order to make it "on-topic" he edited the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm also leaking some memory according to valgrind, but that is only a minor concern for my use case.

Hmm, I don't really agree. Leaking memory is harmless only if you know the cause (*), and simply choose to not spend time in fixing it. In your case, the cause (for one part, see below) is the print loop at the end of the main:

```
while(*strings){
    printf("%s\n", *(strings));
    free(*(strings++));  // incrementing strings here
}

free(strings); // string no longer points to the initially allocated bloc: UB
```

Whether it matters is your problem, but you should not reproduce this code. BTW, it caused a crash on my VS2017...

Now for the function itself:

- `char** strings = malloc(0);` Nothing really bad here because it will be reallocated later, but as it is more of a trick, it really deserves a comment explaining the reason for that line
- Your naming convention for local variables (`int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, stringCount = 0;`) does not help to understand their meaning. After analysis I would prefer:

  ```
  i -> buflen
  j -> seplen
  k -> buf_ix  // or whatever you want saying it is intended to be an index of buf
  l -> sep_ix
  ```
- the strings in `strings` are not null-terminated. This is really bad because there is no way to find the used length: you really should add that terminating null - anyway, you have reserved memory for it...
- An additional memory leak when setting last element of strings to NULL:

  ```
  /* Append NULL to array of strings */
  strings = realloc(strings, (stringCount+1) * sizeof (char *));
  strings[stringCount] = malloc(sizeof NULL);    // hmm... a dynamic allocation...
  strings[stringCount] = NULL;                   // immediately and definitively lost !
  ```

  this code should become:

  ```
  /* Append NULL to array of strings */
  strings = realloc(strings, (stringCount+1) * sizeof (char *));
  strings[stringCount] = NULL;
  ```
- you should test `malloc` and `realloc` return values. Allocation error are uncommon nowadays, but if this code was to run under stressed condition very bad things would occur, because you would be using a null pointer which is Undefined Behaviour (other details on @TobySpeight's answer).

---

(*) Even if you had identified that the code in main caused a memory leak, it could have masked the other memory leak inside the function the deserved to be fixed. That's the reason why it is bad to leave a memory leak in a program, and even in a test only one!

Comment: Note that that `p = realloc(p, n)` is risky, as I explain in [my answer](/a/173767).

Comment: @TobySpeight: I've add it to my answer. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 3):

This is a worthy goal - `strtok()` has a terrible interface, and sorely needs a stateless, thread-safe, non-destructive replacement.

It's inconvenient for the caller to be given ownership of allocated objects.  I'll propose an alternative interface you might like to consider, that's based on existing practice in the standard library:

```
struct view { const char *s, size_t len };
size_t sepstr(struct view *result, size_t n, const char *str, const char *delim)
```

- `result` points to an array of size `n` supplied by the caller.  A null pointer may be passed if `n` is zero.
- `str` and `delim` are the same as your `buf` and `sep` but renamed to be consistent with `strtok()` documentation
- The return value is the number of (possibly empty) tokens found (i.e. one more than the number of delimiters).  This may be greater than `n`, in which case, tokens after the `n`th are not stored in `result`.

This interface means that a caller can use their own memory management (which need not be `malloc()` and `free()`) but can still determine the necessary buffer size, in a similar manner to `snprintf()`.

One disadvantage here is that because we're returning a view into an existing string, we need a length instead of using ordinary null-terminated strings.  The caller may need to copy them into working memory to get null termination.  On the upside, it doesn't need to allocate memory for all the results at once if it only operates on one at a time.

If you combine this with the suggestion to use standard `strstr()` and similar functions, you should end up with a really good replacement for `strtok()`.

Answer (score 1):

C has a function called `strstr` which makes it all easier to read.
It returns a pointer to the first character of the separator it finds or NULL if nothing is found. With pointer arithmetic you can then find out about the length of the string to copy.

Here is a version using `strstr`. It returns a null-terminated array with maximum size 20. If you need a growable array then implement that yourself.

```
char **strsep(char *line, const char *sep)
{
    char **ret = malloc(20 * sizeof(char *));

    char *startp = line, *endp;
    size_t l = strlen(sep);
    int cnt = 0;

    while (endp = strstr(startp, sep))
    {
        ptrdiff_t diff = endp - startp;
        ret[cnt] = malloc(diff + 1);
        strncpy(ret[cnt], startp, diff);
        ret[cnt][diff] = '\0';
        cnt++;
        startp = endp + l;
    }

    if (*startp) // in case last is not a separator
    {
        ret[cnt] = malloc(strlen(startp) + 1);
        strcpy(ret[cnt], startp);
        cnt++;
    }

    ret[cnt] = NULL;

    return ret;
}


int main()
{
    char **x = strsep("foobarfoobarfoo", "bar");

    while (*x)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *x++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Test your allocations

This code seems to assume that memory allocation always succeeds.  That's not true in general - you should always test the return value from `malloc()` and similar.

This is a particularly dangerous anti-pattern:

```
strings = realloc(strings, (stringCount+1) * sizeof (char *));
```

If the allocation fails and returns `NULL`, we can't even `free()` the old memory, because we have overwritten the only pointer to it.